# Round TTime to nearest 15 minutes

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have the following function which I'm led to believe should round time to nearest 15 minutes.

```
function TdmData.RoundTime(T: TTime): TTime;
var h, m, s, ms : Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(T, h, m, s, ms);
  m := (m div 15) * 15;
  s := 0;
  Result := EncodeTime(h, m, s, ms);
end;
```

To test the function I have put a tbutton and a tedit on a form and at the click of the button I do:

```
begin
  Edit1.Text := RoundTime('12:08:27');
end;
```

I get an error when compiling : 'Incompatible types TTime and string'

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: `'12:08:27'` is of type `string`

Comment: Well, a string is not a `TTime`. Your code won't round to nearest, rather it truncates. There's no such thing as `TString` and it's frustrating when people make up error messages. Consider converting from a string to a time.

Comment: [In Delphi: How do I round a TDateTime to closest second, minute, five-minute etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122218/in-delphi-how-do-i-round-a-tdatetime-to-closest-second-minute-five-minute-etc)

Comment: It seems, you lack some experience with data types. See this overview to get a feeling on how data types are used in Delphi: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=DataTypes
Date and time types are a special case of floating point numbers. They are described here: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error which causes the compilation failure is that you are passing a `string` to a function which needs a `TTime` as a parameter.
Once this is fixed, `Edit1.Text` needs a `string` type but your function returns `TTime`.

Using [StrToTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.StrToTime) and [TimeToStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.TimeToStr) you can obtain the desired conversion from and to a `string` type.

Your function can be called like this:

```
begin
  Edit1.Text := TimeToStr(RoundTime(StrToTime('12:08:27'));
end;
```

---

Stealing the [**gabr** user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4997/gabr)'s answer - [In Delphi: How do I round a TDateTime to closest second, minute, five-minute etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122218/in-delphi-how-do-i-round-a-tdatetime-to-closest-second-minute-five-minute-etc/4122475#4122475) - you can obtain a date rounded to an arbitrary nearest value assigned to the `interval` parameter:

```
function RoundToNearest(time, interval: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  time_sec, int_sec, rounded_sec: int64;
begin
  time_sec := Round(time * SecsPerDay);
  int_sec := Round(interval * SecsPerDay);
  rounded_sec := (time_sec div int_sec) * int_sec;
  if ((rounded_sec + int_sec - time_sec) - (time_sec - rounded_sec)) > 0 then
    rounded_sec := rounded_sec + time_sec + int_sec;
  Result := rounded_sec / SecsPerDay;
end;
```

```
begin
  Edit1.Text := TimeToStr(RoundToNearest(StrToTime('12:08:27'), StrToTime('0:0:15')));
end;
```